# History -c, where all the erased histories have been saved and in which directories though?

Tags: linux, bash, security

Usually, when i used (root@example ~ #  history )and it displayed a lot of commands which had been entered before. So, my question is : when i enter "history -c" is to delete all the history at the Unixprompt and where all those histories commands have been saved? which command should I enter to know where all those history command have been saved and in which directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually in the `.bash_history` file located in the home directory

For the `root`, `.bash_history` is located in the `/root` folder.

You may use

```
#find / -type f -name .bash_history #Run as root
```

to see the `.bash_history` files for all users.

Comment: @sjsam...im new to this website and i need 4 more votes to be able to vote you bro !

Comment: Done bro..and i find it very useful ;)

Answer (score 3):

The bash command history will be saved in the location specified by the $HISTFILE environment variable. Normally it will be in ${HOME}/.bash_history.